# The intel x86 emulator accelerator (HAXM installer) revision 6.0.5 is showing not compatible with windows

Tags: android

This a screenshot of the sdk manager message showing the emulator as incompatible with windows:
[image: screenshot of the sdk manager message showing the emulator as incompatible to windows]

I am using android studio, currently version 2.2.3.

Is there an other or older version of the emulator accelerator (HAXM installer) that is compatible with windows 10 ?

Comment: @Anubhav Pandey , were you able to fix the issue

Comment: No...i yet haven't been able to do so.

Comment: the emulator did start to work by following what user341749 told to do but the message displayed by the standalone sdk manager hasn't vanished yet due to which it shows an error whenever android studio tries to request an update for the emulator in the run tab...so i would like to wait for a few more answers

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Try the following

1. download HAXM from Intel
   https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager.
2. Unzip the file and Run intelhaxm-android.exe.
3. Run silent_install.bat.

In my computer Win10 x64 - VS2015 it worked

Comment: i did that but still the problem persists. So, i went through the extracted files and compared them with the ones which were installed earlier and found that the rar file which i downloaded from the intel website lacked a file named "package.xml". does this mean anything?

Comment: I have no idea. Unfortunately. The zip I downloaded from Intel was enough to fix my problem.

Comment: I can confirm that this works. Still no idea why the package is marked as not compatible under the SDK manager.

Comment: @xfx help me here....the emulator opens and works fine in android studio

Comment: ....do you mean that after following the above steps still the sdk manager shows the same message?the emulator opens and works fine in android studio...the main trouble is that the standalone sdk manager still displays the "not compatible in windows" message due to which android studio fails to update the emulator.... i want to check the answer given by user3417479 as atleast it made the emulator working and will do so soon but i am waiting for a full fix.

Comment: @AnubhavPandey: I don't know of any "full fix". The "not compatible with windows" message will continue to appear even after manually installing HAXM from Intel's web site.

Comment: I did same thing but unfortunately not found any solution

Comment: I tried installing this. The log says the following:

   This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) or    it is being exclusively used by Hyper-V. HAXM cannot be installed. 
Please ensure Hyper-V is disabled in Windows Features, or refer to the Intel HAXM documentation for more information.


Meaning one would have to disable Hyper-V or use a Hyper-V emulator.

Comment: On Windows 8.1 I needed to explicitly "Run as Administrator" `silent_install.bat`. Then it worked, I can now run x86 Android emulator.

Comment: This worked on Windows 10.  Ran cmd (As Admin).  Executed both `intelhaxm-android.exe` then `silent_install.bat` as instructed above.  HAXM download from intel was `haxm-windows_v7_0_0.zip`

Comment: I tried the above steps and it works. There is a problem with Android studio installer. It doesn't move after setup, and the silent_install.bat doesn't work. A standalone installer works perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

You likely have Hyper-V enabled. The manual installer provides this detailed notice when it refuses to install on a Windows with it on.

> This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) or it is being exclusively used by Hyper-V. HAXM cannot be installed. 
>   Please ensure Hyper-V is disabled in Windows Features, or refer to the Intel HAXM documentation for more information.

Comment: How to disable Hyper-V on Windows: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3204980/virtualization-applications-do-not-work-together-with-hyper-v-device-g

Answer (score 0):

Did you read https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/03/14/troubleshooting-intel-haxm?

It says "Make sure "Hyper-V", a Windows feature, is not installed/enabled on your system. Hyper-V captures the VT virtualization capability of the CPU, and HAXM and Hyper-V cannot run at the same time. Read this blog: Creating a "no hypervisor" boot entry." https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2008/04/14/creating-a-no-hypervisor-boot-entry/

I've created the boot entry that disables HyperV and it's working