# Why is the intel x86 emulator accelerator (HAXM installer) is showing not compatible with windows?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

Why is the intel x86 emulator accelerator (HAXM installer) is showing not compatible with windows.
I have windows 10 ,64 bit.

[image]

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41092207/the-intel-x86-emulator-accelerator-haxm-installer-revision-6-0-5-is-showing-no

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Check your system have Intel® VT-x Technology.
- If yes then goto bios settings and turn it on.
- Check This Link : https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows.

Comment: Like each of these answers say (in slightly different ways, but this one seems best) - this is NOT Operating System depedent, but it CPU processor dependent (must be running Intel)

Comment: The posted link didn't lead directly.
Can be downloaded from here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-intel-haxm

Answer (score 4):

I did face the same issue (standalone sdk manager showing that its not windows compatible).
 
**Step 1: Open Settings -> Android SDK -> SDK Tools Tab** 
Select the HAXM entry (see the last entry)
[image]

It installed it **successfully!!**

[image] 
**NOTE:** This actually just downloaded the installer. It **did not** install it.

**Step 2: In order to install** check the installer at following location:
***Run the intelhaxm-android.exe***

[image: Install the HAXM]

**Step 3: Restart Android Studio**

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Virtualization option is disabled in BIOS settings. Enable it for HAXM to work.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is not compatibility with Windows, it depends on your CPU (every windows > Windows 7 is compatible but as name says, it is intel so I wouldn't expect anything on AMD CPU) but you have to check in your BIOS if there is option named: Intel Virtualization Technology.

If there is not, you can't emulate anything

If there is just turn it on

Answer (score 0):

First verify that you have Intel® VT-x Technology enabled in the BIOS.

Then download and install HAXM from the link below.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-end-user-license-agreement.