# "intel x86 emulator accelerator" showing "not compatible with windows"+Android Studio asking to update software (although latest)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools, haxm

[image]

1) I have VT-x **enabled** from BIOS recently

2) Hyper-V is **disabled**

3) From a previous answer to this question asked by another user I got to learn that the standalone sdk only downloads the required files but **does not install** it. So he advised that it should be **installed** from: *sdk_location / extras / intel / Hardware_ ...*

***refer to the answer by Amit B:* [Why is the intel x86 emulator accelerator (HAXM installer) is showing not compatible with windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41408552/why-is-the-intel-x86-emulator-accelerator-haxm-installer-is-showing-not-compat)

Tried that also but I got the option to *only* **remove** and not to *install or repair*. 
[image]

4) ran "sc query intelhaxm" from cmd, got state: 4 RUNNING (which means its ok)

[image]

What seems to be the problem then?
Also, Android Studio asked me to update intel haxm, but I have v6.2.1, latest version.

[image]

Anyone faced this kind of problem? Any solution please?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i have to go back to Android 4.0.3 (API Level 15) ... works for me =(