# Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) revision 6.1.1 is showing not compatible with windows

Tags: android, haxm

It is the screenshot of SDK manager
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K59p1.jpg)

I am currently using android version 2.0. 
I desperately need some help. I have already tried solution from this link:
[The intel x86 emulator accelerator (HAXM installer) revision 6.0.5 is showing not compatible with windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41092207/the-intel-x86-emulator-accelerator-haxm-installer-revision-6-0-5-is-showing-no)

Comment: when you tried the above solution, what happened?

Comment: there was no change... @RifatBinReza

Comment: problem persisted