# Android cstdlib error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory (x86)

Tags: android, qt, android-ndk

When deploying **Android for x86** I'm getting an error

> C:\android\android-ndk-r16b\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.9\include\cstdlib:72:
>   error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory `#include<stdlib.h>`

I browsed Google and found many replies to this issue but none of them have solved my problem.

I also double checked my specs:

- My PC (Hardware) : 32 bit
- OS Win 7 : 32 bit
- Qt 5.7.0 : 32 bit
- Android SDK : 32 bit
- Android NDK : 32 bit

When deploying **Desktop MinGW 32 bit** and **Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.7.0)** everything runs perfectly even though "Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.7.0)" is very slow but there's no `stdlib.h` error.

I tried to follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41092207/the-intel-x86-emulator-accelerator-haxm-installer-revision-6-0-5-is-showing-no) to install **HAXM** in order to speed up Android, I followed the steps and everything is now fast but the only problem with that is when debugging on ***Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM)*** I get the error above.

Someone has published a bug corrector [here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=161697) but I'm not sure how to apply it, if it's for my issue.

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: The problem is solved. I was using Android NDK "r16b" version, instead of recommended version 10e.  I had read that but I ignored it.

Comment: Most likely your build system is out of date. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/UnifiedHeaders.md#supporting-unified-headers-in-your-build-system